# Select the lowest of two values

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
id_key acc_id

400001  0009993

500002  0009993
```

I want to select only the value with the lowest id_key on the same acc_id. How can i query such things?

```
SELECT MIN(B.ID_KEY),B.ACC_ID
FROM TEST1 A
LEFT JOIN TEST1 B
ON A.ACC_ID = B.ACC_ID
WHERE A.DATE_A = '2016-01-31' AND A.DATE_B = '2016-01-31'
AND A.ACC_PRFL = 733
ORDER BY B.ACC_ID
```

Comment: Have you read any tutorial or something?

Comment: Have you gone through some tutorials. Your requirement is a very straight-forward one... And query you are using is very complex. Suggest you to please do some more research..

Answer (score 1):

Use MIN and GROUP By functions :

```
 SELECT MIN(id_key) id_key, acc_id
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY acc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
 Select acc_id, min(id_key) as id_key from myTable group by acc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT      MIN(id_key) AS id_key,
            acc_id
FROM        Tab
GROUP BY    acc_id
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/NWBU37038

Hope this helps!!!